# How to subtract a number by the next number?

Tags: python, list

What I have right now:

```
a_list = [25, 23, 12, 8, 4 ,2, 1]
new_list = []
for i, num in enumerate(a_list):  
    new_num = num - num[i+1]
    new_list.append(new_num)

print(new_list)
#Error: new_num = num - num[i+1]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

#Expected: [2, 11, 4, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

`zip` is appropriate here, instead of `enumerate`. Simply zip `a_list` with `a_list[1:]` (so that you can "see" two consecutive elements) and find differences.

```
new_list = [i-j for i, j in zip(a_list, a_list[1:])]
```

The reason `enumerate` doesn't work with your implementation is that you want to index an integer in `a_list` by `num[i+1]` which is nonsensical.

If you absolutely want to use `enumerate`, one important thing is to ensure that you don't want get an IndexError, i.e. you don't want to index beyond the list. One way to ensure that doesn't happen is to only enumerate until `a_list[:-1]`. Then make sure you index `a_list` (and not `num`) and you're good to go.

```
new_list = []
for i, num in enumerate(a_list[:-1]):  
    new_num = num - a_list[i+1]
    new_list.append(new_num)
```

Output:

```
[2, 11, 4, 4, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Maybe would be good to add some explanations for how this works and why OP's code doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
a_list = [25, 23, 12, 8, 4 ,2, 1]

new_list = [a - b for a, b in zip(a_list, a_list[1:])]
print(new_list)
```

If you use a library like `numpy`, this is simpler:

```
import numpy as np

a_arr = np.array([25, 23, 12, 8, 4 ,2, 1])

new_arr = a_arr[:-1] - a_arr[1:]
print(new_arr)
```

Both solutions do the same thing using slicing, taking the original list and pairing each element with the same list, minus the first element. `zip()` automatically omits the last element from the first list, since there is no element to pair it with in the second list. `numpy` wants you to tell it to omit the last element (`a_arr[:-1]`) so that they have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use indices with `num`, which is the value at position `i` in the list, not the list. Iterate over the list with `range(a_list)-1`, so that you access the numbers at positions i and i+1 directly from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's Pretty Simple...What you can do basically just **subtract arr[index] - arr[index + 1]** and append it to a new list and after just print it note **range should be** **(0, old_list.len() - 1)**

```
a_list = [25, 23, 12, 8, 4 ,2, 1]   #old list
nw_lst = []                         #new list to print and where we will append
size = len(a_list);                 #Size of the old_list

for i in range(0, size-1):
    x = a_list[i] - a_list[i + 1]   #claculating difference
    nw_lst.append(x)                #appending the difference to new list
print(nw_lst)                       #printing new list
```

OUTPUT:

```
[2, 11, 4, 4, 2, 1]
```